# AsyncTask.onPostExecute()'s parameters vs instance variable

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Working on my `AsyncTask` I wonder why I should use the `onPostExecute()`'s parameter, when I can just use a class level instance variable in my `AsyncTask` class to share data between `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()`.

Both work, but are there any pro's and con's to each approach?

Edit: when I say 'instance variable', I'm talking about a private instance variable in the `AsyncTask` extended class. When the class dies, the instance variable dies too.

Comment: i assume its useful in case your AsyncTask is written in a separate class file

Comment: This is not the point, because I think that Jop van Raaij meant the class level of AsyncTask itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it may reduce the probability of memory leak, since you do not hold a reference to your object at class level, but only it those AsyncTask methods.

It will also eliminate the synchronization problems, as @nico_ekito mentioned

Comment: I think this answer is valid. However.. Only the `AsyncTask` will have a reference to the instance variable. I do not see a memory leak happing easy. Because `doInBackground()` and `OnPostExecute()` are called synchronously, it's not very probable the JVM is still working on the instance variable when calling `OnPostExcetute()` (if that's even possible).

Answer (score 1):

I have found that using instance variables within the AsyncTask is not thread safe. In my case, if I caught and Exception in doInBackground(), I'd set it to my AsyncTask's Exception instance variable. Then I'd check if the variable was null or not in onPostExecute() (I don't cancel() because I may want to display a message in the exception to the user).

Anyway, from time to time I'd log that I caught an Exception in doInBackground, but in onPostExecute the instance variable would be null. The documentation does say that the methods are called synchronously, so I can't explain WHY that happens, but I saw it happen several times.

Finally, I changed my "Result" class to contain both an exception and the original result I wanted to pass to onPostExecute. That works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the other reasons posted; if you get an exception in the `doInBackground()`, you can just pass a parameter representing an error to your `onPostExecute()` and cancel any additional work, rather than having to get another exception when you realize that all your variables have not been instantiated properly.

Comment: I'd guess you should use `cancel(boolean)`. This will also skip `onPostExecute()`. When you want to work conditional of the state resulting from the stuff you do in `doInBackgroud()`, you have to provide the state in the parameters (ugly to use the same parameter for two types of information), or set an instance variable like `mSuccess` (this solution I saw in some tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to dissent from the accepted answer (and others).

There are absolutely no thread safety concerns about using instance fields in an AsyncTask to pass values from one callback to another. Usually this would mean passing values from `doInBackground()` to `onPostExecute()`. Callbacks in AsyncTask are guaranteed never to execute simultaneously so there are no race conditions, there is also no way for a instance field to be lost or null if it was set in a previously executed callback. Now to the answer.

Pros of `onPostExecute()` parameter:

- The parameter comes from the return value of `doInBackground()` which ensures that `doInBackground()` must provide a value when returning, ensuring it is never forgotten
- The parameter is a clearly established relationship between `doInBackground()` and callbacks that follow: `onPostExecute()` and `onCancelled()`, an instance field could serve several possible purposes

Cons of `onPostExecute()` parameter:

- It is a single parameter, thus you cannot pass two or more values, as a workaround you can wrap multiple values in an class of your creation or perhaps `Pair`

The pros and cons of using an instance field to pass values from `doInBackground()` to `onPostExecute()` are basically the exact inverse of the above.